# Javascript html5 canvas random switch statement

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, switch-statement

I'm trying to randomly select a statement with values inside them which draws from a certain point in the sprite sheet. This is the current code I have.

```
    this.asteroid = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
switch(this.asteroid)
    {
    case 1:
        this.srcX = 0;
        this.srcY = 528;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 33;
        break;
    case 2:
        this.srcX = 32;
        this.srcY = 528;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 33;
        break;  
    case 3:
        this.srcX = 64;
        this.srcY = 528;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 33;
        break;
    case 4:
        this.srcX = 0;
        this.srcY = 565;
        this.width = 62;
        this.height = 60;
        break;
    }
```

I am then later on drawing the values it selects.

The problem I am having its only drawing purple/grey asteroids which are currently case 2 and 3. I have set a font on the main screen telling me which case it draws first and have refreshed until it says 1 or 4 yet it still draws 2 and 3.

Comment: One issue is that Math.floor(Math.random()*4) will generate a number from 0-3. If you want it to generate numbers from 1-4 add a +1 after *4)

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random()*4);` can return 0,1,2,3 but not 4. I can't see why you do not see the case where it returns 1 though.

Answer (score 2):

The way your code is, it currently generates the numbers 0, 1, 2, and 3. So you should be seeing `case 1:` showing up some times, but never `case 4:`. To fix this, just adjust your cases.

Personally, I'd rewrite this code as follows:

```
var srcX = [0,32,64,0],
    srcY = [528,528,32,565],
    width = [32,32,32,62],
    height = [33,33,33,60],
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
this.srcX = srcX[rand];
this.srcY = srcY[rand];
this.width = width[rand];
this.height = height[rand];
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it will random x and y when certain values belong to each other

Answer (score 0):

```
this.asteroid = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
```

Should be 
`this.asteroid = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;` // So you could count the `case 4` and "hop" over the `case 0`

See in the console:
http://jsbin.com/ulirom/3/